# Syncing between Memory, IsoStorage and Server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, design-patterns, memory, synchronization

I have a DataService, which holds a list of string.

- List should be returned fast, so i'm keeping it in memory, in a List of strings. I'm using **GetList** and **SetList** for working with memory.
- List should be resistable to app closing/tombstoning, so i'm also keeping it in file. I'm using **ReadList** and **WriteList** for working with IsoStorage.
- List should be synchronized with server, so i have some async calls for that. Using **PushList** and **PullList** for syncing with server.

I have a feeling that i'm inventing a bicycle. Is there any patterns for smooth sync?

---

EDIT: what i got so far. Actually, what is needed is a getter

```
async List<Items> GetList()
{
    if (list != null) return list; // get from memory

    var listFromIso = await IsoManager.ReadListAsync();
    if (listFromIso != null) return listFromIso; // get, well, from iso

    var answer = await NetworkManager.PullListAsync(SERVER_REQUEST);
    if (answer.Status = StatusOK) return answer.List; // get from.. guess where? :)
}
```

And setter, the same just reverse. Please, share your ideas/experience.

Answer (score 0):

Could a decorator help?

```
interface DataService
{
    IList<Items> GetList();
    void SetList(IList<Items> items);
}

class InMemoryDataService : DataService
{
    public InMemoryDataService(DataService other)
    {
        Other = other;
    }

    public IList<Items> GetList()
    {
        if (!Items.Any())
        {
            Items = Other.GetList();
        }

        return Items;
    }

    public void SetList(IList<Items> items)
    {
        Items = items;
        Other.SetList(items);
    }

    private IList<Items> Items { get; set; }
    private DataService Other { get; set; }
}

class IsoStorageDataService : DataService
{
    public IsoStorageDataService(DataService other)
    {
        Other = other;
    }

    public IList<Items> GetList()
    {
        ...
    }

    private DataService Other { get; set; }
}
```